# SwiftUI: GridLayout does not render grid

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to implement [GridLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gridlayout) and can't get it to work. (I'm not using `Grid`, as I need conformance to `AnyLayout`)

The following code generates the appearance of a `VStack` although I would expect a grid.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GridLayout(alignment: .leading, horizontalSpacing: 10, verticalSpacing: 10) {
            ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                Rectangle()
                    .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(idealHeight: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a grid. You haven't specified any `GridRow`s so there is only one column per row.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought using `GridLayout` would not require `GridRow`.